# MongoEngine delete dict key from object field

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, flask-mongoengine

I have a pretty complex Flask website with lots of DB interaction but have got stuck with a seemingly simple delete function!
I am  trying to delete key 56 from sensordict  in the (simplified) SiteConfig document below  using MongoEngine

```
{ 
"_id" : "12345", 
"sensordict" : {
    "56" : {
        "currentval" : 1.2, 
        "devicetype" : NumberInt(2)
    }, 
    "70" : {
        "currentval" : 31.0, 
        "devicetype" : NumberInt(2)
    }
}, 
"siteserial" : "45678", 
"status" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

Code tried below where sensorid = '56':

```
def delete_sensor(siteconfig, sensorid):

    dbsite = SiteConfig.objects(id=siteconfig.id).first()
    dbsite.update(unset__sensordict__S=sensorid)
    dbsite.save()
```

The code is failing at the update with mongoengine.errors.OperationError: Update failed (The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: sensordict.$)

I suspect this is a simple one but have been way down the rabbit hole for a couple of hours on this one and any help would be much appreciated
Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 1):

`dbsite.update(unset__sensordict__S=sensorid)` should be `dbsite.update(unset__sensordict__56=1)` since you have to unset the field with key '56'. This should work